# What are the open sets in $(\mathbb Z, |\cdot|)$ with the standard metric?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Is $\{0\}$ open in $\mathbb Z$? I think so because if we are working in $\mathbb Z$, we are not looking at other numbers such as the rationals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. For any positive $\epsilon<1$, the basis element $B_{\epsilon}(0)$ contains all integers of distance at most $\epsilon$ away. Only $0$ satisfies this, so $B_{\epsilon}(0) = \{0\}$, thus $\{0\}$ is open.

Comment: So, every subset of $\mathbb Z$ is open? If we work in $\mathbb Q$ with the standard metric, is every subset open too?

Comment: Your first statement is true — it turns out that the metric topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ with the standard metric is just the discrete topology. This does not follow for $\mathbb{Q}$ however. Why not?

Comment: Oh ok. For $\mathbb Q$, if we have subset such $[x,y]$, where this stands for all the rationals between $x$ and $y$, then a neighborhood around $x$ will contain points outside of $[x,y]$. Is this correct?

Comment: Exactly — thus this topology can’t be the discrete topology. Note that it is important for either $x$ or $y$ to be rational, just to be explicit about your counterexample.

Comment: A lukewarm addendum: $\mathbb Q$ is neither closed nor open in the subspace topology. Clearly, it does not contain all of its limit points, since there exists a sequence of rational numbers that do not converge to a rational, and likewise it cannot be open for the reason you mentioned. +1 by the way....